# NodeJS RADIUS OTP authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, cas, freeradius, radius

I am trying to implement RADIUS OTP authentication in NodeJS.
I could not find much information and if it's at all possible. 
NodeJS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/radius
Any directions would be very helpful.

I have implemented the same on Java platform using CAS RADIUS and that work fine.
CAS: https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/mfa/RADIUS-Authentication.html#

Answer (score 2):

Here is some information and guidance.

Is it possible? Yes.

Nodejs Radius Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/radius
Nodejs OTP Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/otplib

Example of using the radius package for OTP: https://github.com/mcguinness/simple-radius-server

You should be able to fork the example and modify it to use the OTP package to generate the OTP tokens.

Another possibility would be to deploy FreeIPA in a docker container and then use ldapjs to auth against the FreeIPA container from node. See code below for an example of how to do auth against FreeIPA using ldapjs.

```js
const LDAP = require('ldapjs');

class LDAPAuth {
    constructor({url, base, uid}) {
        this.errorCount = 0
        setInterval(()=>this.errorCount = 0, 10000)
        let self = this
        function createLdap() {
            self.ldap = LDAP.createClient({url})
                .on('error', (error)=> {
                    console.error('Error in ldap',error)
                    self.errorCount++
                    if (self.errorCount > 20) {
                        console.error('Too many errors! Giving up...')
                        process.exit()
                    } else {
                        createLdap()
                    }
                })
        }
        createLdap()
        this.base = base
        this.uid = uid
    }

    authenicate({username, password, count = 0}) {
        let dn = `${this.uid}=${username},${this.base}`
        if (count > 5) {
            return Promise.reject('Failed to authenticate with LDAP!')
        }
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
            this.ldap.bind(dn, password, (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    if (err && err.stack && err.stack.indexOf(`${this.url} closed`) > -1) {
                        count++
                        // wait 1 second to give the ldap error handler time to reconnect
                        return setTimeout(()=>resolve(this.authenicate({username, password})), 2000)
                    }
                    console.error('ldap error', err)
                    reject(err)
                }
                if (res) resolve()
                else reject()
            })
        })

    }
}

module.exports = LDAPAuth
```

note: The code example has issues and I would not write it this way now but has been functioning well for a few years now so not going to touch it unless a need arises.

Comment: Many thanks, later on, the investigation I understood our existing 4TRESS setup already act as a server. So I just used the client code from https://github.com/retailnext/node-radius/blob/master/examples/auth_client.js and it worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but you can easily extend [node-radius-server](https://github.com/simllll/node-radius-server) to cope with OTP.